# Oauth Consumer API for SpringBoot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Third Party application is using OAuth2.0 with refresh_token grant-type for authentication. For building a spring-boot application, I am looking for any library which can handle the Oauth while consuming the third-party API.

I am comfortable in writing the logic, but reusing any production-ready API is preferred.

Can anyone suggest a robust API which can handle the OAuth for making the Third-Party request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`spring-security-oauth`](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-oauth) - native spring library

[`Scribe`](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava) - light java alternative